# laravel withCount is only showing id values, not the count values

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the count value of matching records from a related table, using Laravel 8 (Eloquent). The idea is simply to count the number of tasks assigned to each user.

I'm trying to determine an easy way to do this with Laravel's Eloquent query builder.

Here is the DB schema & some sample values:

```
create table user_tasks (
    id integer primary key,
    user_id integer not null
);

create table users (
    id integer primary key,
    name text not null
);

insert into user_tasks values (1, 1);
insert into user_tasks values (2, 2);
insert into user_tasks values (3, 1);
insert into user_tasks values (4, 1);
insert into user_tasks values (5, 1);
insert into user_tasks values (6, 2);

insert into users values (1, 'joe');
insert into users values (2, 'sally');
insert into users values (3, 'bob');
```

The output should be:

```
1, 'joe', 4
2, 'sally', 2
3, 'bob', 0
```

This is what I am starting with:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function getTaskCount()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User\Task', 'user_id');
    } 
}

$result = User::select(['id'])
    ->withCount('getTaskCount')
    ->get();
```

However, this is outputting:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

In other words, there is no count value. I have only shown small samples from my controller & model classes (the important parts), but what could be some reasons that the review count values are not showing alongside the "id" values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does `withCount` do and how to use it?

> The `withCount` method should be used to append a `{relation}_count` attribute to the results of your query, where `{relation}` is the name of the relationship method defined in your model which will count the total number of entries in you related table.

##### Now let's correct your code

If your table is `user_tasks` Your model should be named `UserTask` as this is naming convention in Laravel.
and then change your relationship like this,

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserTask::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Your `UserTask` model exists and is correctly set up:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserTask extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_tasks';
    
    // write your other code like fillable, belongsTo relationship etc
}
```

Now, adjust your query to correctly reference this relationship and include the name of the user as well:

```
$result = User::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->withCount('tasks')
    ->get();
```

With this query, each `User` object in the result set will have an additional attribute named `tasks_count` that contains the count of related `UserTask` records.

Comment: it turned out to be the $visible array of the model that was preventing the display of the tasks_count value